What is the simplest first-order formula with a binary predicate whose models are all infinite?
It’s possible to write a first-order logic formula about a binary predicate $xRy$ such that all models of that formula are infinite. This earlier question gives several different ways to do this.
My question is whether there is a “simplest” such formula. Stated more precisely: define the length of a first-order formula $\phi$ to be number of symbols needed to write out $\phi$, excluding whitespace and parentheses. What is (are) the shortest-length element(s) of $\{ \ \phi \ | \ \text{all models of } \phi \text{ are infinite } \}$? (Or, perhaps, are there any proof-theoretic obstacles to determining which formulae these are?)

I don't see how there can be any proof-theoretic obstacles to finding which formula is the shortest in your set, as we can put an upper bound on the size of the formulas, because we already have examples, so the number of formulas we have to look at is finite (given a sensible way of choosing bound variables). The answer will depend on exactly how we formulate former-logic (e.g., whether we include equality or function symbols).So yes, maximally simple formulas of the kind you are interested in must exist, but it doesn't look like a very useful exercise to try to find them.

@RobArthan The question of whether a given formula has only infinite models is not in general decidable, so there could very well be proof-theoretic obstacles to finding a simplest example. I actually find this question quite interesting, FWIW.

Simplest is a badly defined and not very natural condition, since is hoghly dependent on the peculiar notation of first order logic. Such questions can be amusing, but they tend to not lead to much.

@ThomasAndrews I agree that this particular measure of complexity isn't great, but I think the right response is to suggest a better way of asking the question instead of implicitly dismissing the entire idea.

@Noah: that point of that part of my comment was specifically about "whether there is a "simplest" such formula" and not whether we can decide what the simplest formulas are.

@RobArthan But the OP specifically wrote "Or, perhaps, are there any proof-theoretic obstacles to determining which formulae these are" (emphasis mine), so I don't see how that is relevant. And you wrote "I don't see how there can be any proof-theoretic obstacles to finding which formula is the shortest in your set" (again, emph. mine). I don't think anyone was asking about existence as such.

@NoahSchweber: well that's the perennial two questions in one problem on MSE.

@RobArthan I mean, they immediately followed the "whether there is" bit with "stated more precisely," so I don't really think this is a two-questions-in-one situation. I think they just used "there is" as a shorthand for "we can find," which isn't that uncommon in my experience.

@NoahSchweber I couldn't conceive of another way of phrasing it. This kind of thing is most;y just "fun" rather than having a deep meaning. We can define all sorts of complexity metrics, I suppose, but I don't see using a "better" metric as the problem.

The sentence "My question is whether there is such a "simplest" question" is the one I was talking about.

@ThomasAndrews I would disagree; "better" metrics are extensively studied in mathematical logic. See e.g. work on finite-variable logics (for "number of variables"), model theory of quantifier prefixes (for "number of quantifiers"), etc. See e.g. https://www.jstor.org/stable/3062204.

@NoahSchweber I didn't say they don't exist. Better metrics exist, better metrics which make the answer to this question more interesting do not exist, as far as I know. IMy comment doesn't change with better metrics - the answer to the question still reveals nothing interesting.

@ThomasAndrews I think we may disagree about what is interesting. For myself I find that, when the complexity measure is reasonable, minimality results are intrinsically interesting.

Call such a sentence an infinity-sentence (the term "axiom of infinity" is actually used in this context but I find that confusing). The shortest infinity-sentence I can whip up is $$\forall x\exists y\forall z[\neg R(x,x)\wedge [R(z,x)\rightarrow R(z,y)]\wedge R(x,y)],$$ which improves slightly on the more obvious "$R$ is a transitive irreflexive relation with no greatest element." I wouldn't be surprised if incremental improvements were possible.
However, as Rob Arthan and Thomas Andrews have commented above, I don't really think that length as such is particularly interesting. Proving lower bounds is rather difficult in any situation, and it's especially so when the measure of complexity is as fine as length. For example, the exact length of the sentence above depends on whether or not we take "$\rightarrow$" as primitive.
Coarser measures of length lend themselves more easily to lower bounds since they admit simpler invariants, and are also more meaningful inasmuch as they are less sensitive to tweaks of syntax. Here are a few questions in terms of such coarser measures which might be easier to tackle than the full optimality question for the sentence above:

Is there an infinity-sentence in which $R$ occurs at most three times?

Is there an infinity-sentence using only two variables (or if we want to avoid clever variable reuse, using only two quantifiers)?

Is there an infinity-sentence of the form $\exists x\forall y\exists z\theta$ with $\theta$ quantifier-free?


If memory serves, the answer to the second question is already known to be negative; I'll see if I can track down a reference (or whip up a proof) for this. The first and third questions, though, I suspect are quite tricky. The "$\exists\forall$"-version of the third question has an easy negative answer, but even the "$\forall\exists$"-analogue is tricky. For example, there is a "$(\forall\wedge\exists)$-type" infinity-sentence in the language consisting of two unary function symbols $f$ and $g$ (which moreover only uses a single variable):

 $\forall x[g(f(x))=x\wedge f(x)\not=x]\wedge\exists x[g(x)=x]$. The first clause forces $f$ to be injective while any $a$ witnessing the second clause must have no $f$-preimage, so the domain must be infinite.

So showing that a $\forall\exists\forall$-prefix is optimal here will need to use particular properties of the language $\{R\}$ chosen (e.g. in ruling out an $\exists\forall$-infinity-sentence, we use the fact that every finite subset of a structure is in fact the underlying set of a substructure, which breaks down when function symbols appear).
And for the first question I have absolutely no idea.

To reduce the number of occurrences of $R$ by one, either change $\neg Rxx \land (Rzx \to Rzy)$ to $Rzx \to (Rzy \land z \neq x)$ or change $(Rzx \to Rzy) \land Rxy$ to $(Rzx \lor z = x) \to Rzy$.
